# Calico : Virtual Network Interfaces not created by calico

Tags: linux-networking, kubernetes, calico

I had been using calico-policy-only (v 3.22) mode with kubernetes 1.24.1 in my worker nodes. Recently worker nodes were upgraded to 1.25.4 , so for compatibility we had to upgrade calico as well to ver 3.25.

Calico poliy only https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/release-v3.25/manifests/calico-policy-only.yaml

After upgrade -> calico-node pods started showing logs ->

```
2023-06-12T14:28:10.164964531Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.164 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 589: Interface missing, will retry if it appears. ifaceName="calie9798b8b1fb" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.164964531Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.164 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 1181: Failed to access interface because it doesn't exist. error=Link not found ifaceName="calib12e6189458" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.165122449Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.164 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 1249: Failed to get interface; it's down/gone. error=Link not found ifaceName="calib12e6189458" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.165241012Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.164 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 589: Interface missing, will retry if it appears. ifaceName="calib12e6189458" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.165395313Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.165 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 1181: Failed to access interface because it doesn't exist. error=Link not found ifaceName="calic92537802cb" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.165395313Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.165 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 1249: Failed to get interface; it's down/gone. error=Link not found ifaceName="calic92537802cb" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.165649382Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.165 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 589: Interface missing, will retry if it appears. ifaceName="calic92537802cb" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.165780200Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.165 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 1181: Failed to access interface because it doesn't exist. error=Link not found ifaceName="cali6f3e8804ec6" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.165780200Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.165 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 1249: Failed to get interface; it's down/gone. error=Link not found ifaceName="cali6f3e8804ec6" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.165977461Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.165 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 589: Interface missing, will retry if it appears. ifaceName="cali6f3e8804ec6" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.166135029Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.165 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 1181: Failed to access interface because it doesn't exist. error=Link not found ifaceName="cali823447cfd40" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.166184371Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.166 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 1249: Failed to get interface; it's down/gone. error=Link not found ifaceName="cali823447cfd40" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.166285733Z 2023-06-12 14:28:10.166 [INFO][825] felix/route_table.go 589: Interface missing, will retry if it appears. ifaceName="cali823447cfd40" ifaceRegex="^cali.*" ipVersion=0x4 tableIndex=254
2023-06-12T14:28:10.
```

I also checked worker nodes by ifconfig , It doesn't list any cali* prefixed interfaces.

What could be the reason that calico is not able to create network interfaces. Although all calico pods are running (kube-controllers and typha also fine with no failure logs , and calico-node pods are also ready - but they do have above logs)

Also , after applying calico, the pods to be configured by calico , are also not being configured and have no "projectcalico" annotation appended after I recreate the pods. Hence policies are also not working. Basically I'm suspecting since no network interfaces are created , it is missing configuring pods on the network.

Any idea what could be missing here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @devcodes can you ping us the documentation that you are following or any  steps for replicating the issue

Comment: I am using this doc - https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengsettingupcalico.htm , using calico alongside flannel